# How to use object filter with softlayer rest api?

Tags: rest, filter, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I read [this article](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters) and have some problems trying to follow the examples. The following is one of the examples given in that article. The first parameter in the object filter is *virtualGuests*. This object filter can be used in api *https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/VirtualGuests*.

```
object_filter = {
'virtualGuests': {
    'datacenter': {
        'name': {'operation': 'dal05'}
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the object filter in other api methods, like *SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups* for example. My question is how to get/set the first parameter like *virtualGuests*? I tried several times but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these recomendations: **Getting first parameter through Service Datatype** or **How to define the first parameter as simple way?**

---

### Getting first parameter through Service Datatype

You are trying to get

- [SoftLayer_Account::getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups)

As you see, you are using **SoftLayer_Account** service, you need to open its datatype from this service:

- You can go here:
  http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account and
  click on "**datatypes**" label/option
- Or go directly here:
  [SoftLayer_Account](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account)

So, you need to start here, the method that you are using is **getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups**, if you want to get this information in the datatypes, you should skip the word "**get**" and looking for "**BlockDeviceTemplateGroups**" property, so you will have the correct parameter that you need to set at first.

[image]

---

### How to define the first parameter as simple way?

If you notice, the only changes were: skip "**get**" word from the method, in this case is "**getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups**", so it will be:

> "BlockDeviceTemplateGroups"

The next step should be set the first char in lowercase like:

> "blockDeviceTemplateGroups"

So, it should be the filter:

```
object_filter = {
'blockDeviceTemplateGroups': {
    'datacenter': {
        'name': {'operation': 'dal05'}
        }
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)
- [Going Further with the SoftLayer API Python Client - Part
  1](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1)

Comment: Very detailed, really appreciate!

Comment: I have created a VM on ams01 in my SoftLayer account and I am trying to filter by datacenter name. Even if I specify the datacenter name as dal05, I get the JSON for ams01 only.This is how I have created my URL : @api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"datacenter": {"name":{"operation":"ams01"}}}
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try the following request:
**https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"ams01"}}}}**