# Not able to filter portable storage by id

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following API and trying to filter by "id" but in vain. Hoping for some help,

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectMask=mask[id,capacity]&objectFilter={"id": {"operation":  xxxx}}

where "xxxx" is replaced by the id of the virtual server

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"id":{"operation":xxxx}}}

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)
- [How to use object filter with softlayer rest
  api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api/41189063#41189063)

Comment: Thanks Ruber, that helped me