# How to get the disk size of portable disks via cURL

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to get the portable disk size per each of my vms.

1. Get ID of VMs by requesting 
   curl --user ":" -sk https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualDiskImages
2. Get List of VMs by requesting with Key=ID 
   curl --user ":" -sk https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3//SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/*Key*
3. No method to get PortableStorageVolumes with key=VM's ID

There is only method to get PortableStorageVolumes under 'SoftLayer_Account' so that i cannot get volume size per vm id.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not method in [SoftLayer_VIrtual_Guest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest) service which can help to retrieve portable storage volumes information.

As workaround, It's possible to get this information through [SoftLayer_Account::getPortableStorageVolumes](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes) but we need to use an [Object Filter](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters), below a request which can help to retrieve Portable Storage for a specific Virtual Guest:

```
curl -k "https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDevices":{"guest":{"id":{"operation":123123123}}}}}"
```

**Replace:** $user, $apiKey and 123123123(VSI id) with your own information

If you have a problem with encoding, try this:

```
curl -k "https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter=%7B%22portableStorageVolumes%22%3A%7B%22blockDevices%22%3A%7B%22guest%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A123123123%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D"
```

**Replace:** $user, $apiKey and 123123123(VirtualGuest's id)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But i do not understand well how to use objectFilter and what i should specify there. it seems to be using DB table relationship, could you please explain me this part?

objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDevices":{"guest":{"id":{"operation":123123123}}}}}"

Comment: Review this forum please: [How to use object filter with softlayer rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api) it provides information about them, let me know any doubt or comment