# How to get iSCSI credentials for specific Virtual Guest

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using this request to get the credentials to the iSCSI disk 000001 for the virtual guest 000002:

```
GET /rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/000001/getObject.json?objectMask=filteredMask[allowedVirtualGuests[allowedHost[credential]]]&objectFilter={"allowedVirtualGuests":{"id":000002}}
```

However, the result is the same as if I wouldn't apply the objectFilter part at all, resulting in the credentials for *all virtual guests* being returned, instead of the single one that I need.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following REST call:

```
GET /rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/000001/getAllowedVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[allowedHost[credential]]&objectFilter={"allowedVirtualGuests":{"id":{"operation":000002}}}
```

You can use object-filters when the method returns a list of objects, **getObject** returns only one which is the [SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi) itself, on the other hand the method **getAllowedVirtualGuests** returns a list of virtual guests.

I recommend to review the following links to know more about this:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage_iscsi/getallowedvirtualguests

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

[How to use object filter with softlayer rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api)