# Softlayer go api, filter recent events by date

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to filter the recent softlayer events by data via the API, for example setting up the following filter to get events modified in the last 48 hours

```
f := filter.Path("modifyDate").DateAfter(time.Now().Add(-48 * time.Hour).Format("01/02/2006 15:04:05")).Build()
```

And I call it via

```
resp, err := AccountService.Filter(f).GetRecentEvents()
```

I have tried time formats with date and time and just date in the form mm/dd/yyyy
With debug enabled I can see this generates the following filter

```
2018/04/09 17:29:45 {"modifyDate":{"operation":"greaterThanDate","options":[{"name":"date","value":["04/07/2018 17:29:45"]}]}}
2018/04/09 17:36:22 [DEBUG] Request URL:  GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getRecentEvents.json?objectFilter=%7B%22modifyDate%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22greaterThanDate%22%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%2204%2F07%2F2018+17%3A36%3A22%22%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D
2018/04/09 17:36:22 [DEBUG] Parameters:
2018/04/09 17:36:23 [DEBUG] Status Code:  200
```

Unfortunately this always returns the same results. How should I construct my query for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following example:

f := `{"recentEvents": {"modifyDate": {"operation": "greaterThanDate","options": [{"name": "date","value": ["03/21/2018 17:29:44"]}]}}}`

resp, err := service.Filter(f).GetRecentEvents()

For more information you could review the following:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go

Comment: That works great thanks, how did you know that the filter needed an outer `"recentEvents"`?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. And about the outer "recentEvents" it`s just the method in the request, taking out the first word and beginning it with lowercase, so in example if you used "getVirtualGuests" method, the filter should begin with "virtualGuests". You can get further information on the following site: https://softlayer.github.io/article/object-filters/ and get more examples like that.

Comment: @AI S-M, you can also review the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api to know about how to use filters